# Relation between Keras model and backend session

Tags: session, tensorflow, keras

It is known that `tensorflow` uses static graph to define a model and we have to run a session to evaluate. While `keras` seems to be simpler and can be used as common library. But when we use `keras` to build model and `backend.set_session` of `keras` together, some problems occur. Look at the following example

```
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import keras.backend as K

def build_model(advantange='avg'):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(3, input_shape=(3,)))
    # optimizer
    adam = Adam(lr=1E-3)
    # model compile
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=adam)
    return model

nn1 = build_model()
nn2 = build_model()
nn1.set_weights(nn2.get_weights())

K.set_session(tf.Session())
print(K.get_value(nn1.optimizer.lr))
```

here we build two independent model (same architecture) `nn1` and `nn2` and try to just print the inner learning rate of them, and we got the following error

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value Adam/lr
```

It seems that the model `nn1` and `nn2` are not initialized. But if we just delete the line

```
nn1.set_weights(nn2.get_weights())
```

or delete the line of

```
K.set_session(tf.Session())
```

then we can get the learning rate to be `0.001` correctly.

This really bothers me because I have no idea to the cause of this problem. Especially I don't understand the relation between `keras` model and `backend` session. How to solve the problem without deleting the two lines given above ?

PS: I realize that it might be because of the conflict between `tf.Session` and `keras` default session. If no self-defined `tf.Session` is set, then the program will run under the default session given by keras. However, when `tf.Session` is given, it is different from the session of `keras` model. Such difference will cause confliction and error.